# Rails, Embert: view as a single page web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, single-page-application

I have Rails app and I need to add client-rich view. The best way to do it is to use Javascript MVC framework, right? So, I choose Ember.js. But there is one problem: it seems like Embert usage suggests that I have only one view. How to organise code right?

**UPD:**
If I use ember-rails gem, it loads Ember for all views. How to load Ember for only one view?

Comment: I think you are pretty much going to have to translate all your existing `app/views/**` into ember views `app/assets/javascripts/views/**`

Comment: So, @Doon, you want to say that if I use ember I have to use only one rails view?

Comment: WEll Most Ember apps are Single Page right?  At that point rails isn't really using views and the like anymore and it is pretty much a data provider.  So you might still be using the rails "views" to format your json, but as far as html/frontend they will all be via ember

Comment: it probably adds it your assets,  remove the ember includes from your javascripts/application.js file so they are not included in all views,  and just include them in your ember view.